# How to get the filename of a document given the document ID

Tags: list, csom, document, document-id

I want to create a web part where:

based on a given document ID, I need to get the corresponding filename of the document.

So this is my function to get the document and my question is how can I modify it to get the name instead of the whole document?

```
private void GetDocument(string UNIQUE_DOC_ID)
{
 string siteUrl= "...";
 ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
 List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents"); 
 CamlQuery camlQueryDocs = new CamlQuery();
 camlQueryDocs.ViewXml =
  @"<View>
   <Query>
     <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='ID' /> // Not sure about the field name. It can also be _dlc_DocId
      <Value Type='Text'>" + UNIQUE_DOC_ID + @"</Value>
    </Eq>
     </Where>
   </Query>
    </View>";
 document = documentsList.GetItems(camlQueryDocs);
 
    clientContext.Load(document);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the column name as "FileLeafRef" in viewfield to get only specified details of document

```
private void GetDocument(string UNIQUE_DOC_ID)
{
string siteUrl= "...";
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents"); 
CamlQuery camlQueryDocs = new CamlQuery();
camlQueryDocs.ViewXml =
@"<View>
 <Query>
 <Where>
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='ID' /> // Not sure about the field name. It can also be _dlc_DocId
  <Value Type='Text'>" + UNIQUE_DOC_ID + @"</Value>
</Eq>
 </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
</ViewFields>
</View>";
document = documentsList.GetItems(camlQueryDocs);

clientContext.Load(document);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}​
```